# Uploading large file to SharePoint 2013 results empty 0Kb file

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, file-upload

I need to upload a couple of large archives to a SharePoint's document library, but anytime the upload finishes, the uploaded file is 0KB.

Tried the following upload options, which all resulted the same issue:

1. Explorer View (Client)
2. Drag and Drop (Client)
3. Mapped drive (Client)
4. Mapped drive (Server)

Additional details:

- SharePoint version: 2013 Foundation
- File size: 4GB (split into 4 parts, 1GB per each)
- The maximum allowed upload: 2000MB (set in Web Application General Settings)
- Available hard drive space: 40GB+
- Site collection: newly created, not containing any data

Does anyone have any ideas what else I should look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is having similar issues, my solution was the following:

> Uploaded files, and gave it some time (appx. 2 hours), after which
>   refreshed the explorer view and discovered that file size showed
>   correct value.

I think this is caused by processing the large files during upload, since they are saved in DB instead of File-system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since basically the upload system is under classic asp.net
application configuration, can you check the web.config lines

let me know if it helps! :)
cheers

Comment: i was referring to 
`code`
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
`code`
"xxx" is in KB. The default is 4096 (= 4 MB).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it worked after some period of time. I just left the file as it is with 0KB, and was monitoring it refreshing the DL it was stored in. After approximately 2 hours it showed the correct file size.

Comment: @EmilGurbanov Thanks for sharing that. I had an issue with zip files showing up empty in SharePoint; never thought to wait a while and check again later. You should post this as the answer so others with the same problem. can find it.